# Is there a way AND/OR conditional operator in terraform?

Tags: terraform

Is there a way to use something like this in Terraform?

> count = "${var.I_am_true}"&&"${var.I_am_false}"

Comment: I think not last time I checked. But you might find something from their Issues tracking: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues

Comment: for Terraform 0.11 (2018) see my answer below

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The answer by deniszh is pretty close, but I thought I'd clarify it a bit and clean up the syntax.

In Terraform, a boolean `true` is converted to a `1` and a boolean `false` is converted to a `0`. So if you have two boolean variables, `var.foo` and `var.bar`, you can represent `AND` using simple multiplication:

```
count = "${var.foo * var.bar}"
```

In the code above, `count` will be 1 only if `var.foo` AND `var.bar` are both `true`, as 1 * 1 is 1. In all other cases (1 * 0, 0 * 1, 0 * 0), you get 0.

To represent OR, you can take advantage of the function [signum(x)](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html#signum_int_), which returns 1 if the `x` you pass in is a positive number, 0 if `x` is 0, and -1 if `x` is a negative number. Taking this into account, here is OR:

```
count = "${signum(var.foo + var.bar)}"
```

In the code above, `count` will be 1 if either `var.foo` OR `var.bar` is `true` and 0 only if both are `false` (`signum(1 + 1) = 1`, `signum(1 + 0) = 1`, `signum(0 + 1) = 1`, `signum(0 + 0) = 0`).

Note that to use the techniques above, you must take care to set the variables to a boolean and NOT a string. You want this:

```
variable "foo" {
  # Proper boolean usage
  default = true
}
```

NOT this:

```
variable "foo" {
  # THIS WILL NOT WORK!
  default = "true"
}
```

For more info on how to do a variety of Terraform conditionals, check out [Terraform tips & tricks: loops, if-statements, and gotchas](https://blog.gruntwork.io/terraform-tips-tricks-loops-if-statements-and-gotchas-f739bbae55f9) and *[Terraform: Up & Running](http://www.terraformupandrunning.com/)*.

Answer (score 134):

This is more appropriate in the actual version (0.12.X)

> The supported operators are:
>
> Equality: == and !=
> Numerical comparison: >, <, >=, <=
> Boolean logic: &&, ||, unary !

https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html#conditionals

condition_one and condition two:

```
count = var.condition_one && var.condition_two ? 1 : 0
```

condition_one and NOT condition_two:

```
count = var.condition_one && !var.condition_two ? 1 : 0
```

condition_one OR condition_two:

```
count = var.condition_one || var.condition_two ? 1 : 0
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer for the current tf version.

Comment: Can you tell me why terraform continue to the check the 2nd argument `if var.x != null && var.x.internal_value` it keeps failing on the 2nd condition, but if the 1st is `false` because my argument is really null - it fails on `var.x.internal_value` but why it continues ?

Comment: @RickyLevi I believe it is because of this reason: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/operators#logical-operators  

The logical operators in Terraform do not short-circuit

Answer (score 13):

[Terraform 0.8](https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/terraform-0-8.html) added first class support for [conditional logic](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html#conditionals) rather than the previous hacky workarounds.

This uses the classic ternary syntax so now you can do something like this:

```
variable "env" { default = "development" }

resource "aws_instance" "production_server" {
  count = "${var.env == "production" ? 1 : 0}"
  ...
}
```

Now this will only create the `production_server` EC2 instance when `env` is set to `"production"`.

You can also use it in other places too such as setting a variable/parameter like this:

```
variable "env" { default = "development" }
variable "production_variable" { default = "foo" }
variable "development_variable" { default = "bar" }

output "example" {
  value = "${var.env == "production" ? var.production_variable : var.development_variable}"
}
```

One thing to be aware of is that Terraform actually evaluates both sides before then choosing the value used in the ternary statement rather than lazily evaluating just the side of the ternary that the logic will trigger.

This means you can't do something like this recent example of me trying to hack around an issue with the [`aws_route53_zone` data source](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/route53_zone.html):

```
variable "vpc"    {}
variable "domain" {}

variable "private_zone"  { default = "true" }

data "aws_vpc" "vpc" {
  filter {
    name   =   "tag-key"
    values = [ "Name" ]
  }
  filter {
    name   =   "tag-value"
    values = [ "${var.vpc}" ]
  }
}

data "aws_route53_zone" "private_zone" {
  count        = "${var.private_zone == "true" ? 1 : 0}"
  name         = "${var.domain}"
  vpc_id       = "${data.aws_vpc.vpc.id}"
  private_zone = "true"
}

data "aws_route53_zone" "public_zone" {
  count        = "${var.private_zone == "true" ? 0 : 1}"
  name         = "${var.domain}"
  private_zone = "false"
}

output "zone_id" {
  value = "${var.private_zone == "true" ? data.aws_route53_zone.private_zone.zone_id : data.aws_route53_zone.public_zone.zone_id}"
}
```

In the above example this will fail on the plan because either `data.aws_route53_zone.private_zone.zone_id` or `data.aws_route53_zone.public_zone.zone_id` is not defined depending on whether `public_zone` is set to true or false.

Answer (score 6):

All the answers are enough but there is another case too.

For example, you have `multiple` environments like;

- `master`
- `dev`
- `staging`

and you need to set value of `OBJECT_ENABLE` key based on these environments. You can do this like following:

```
OBJECT_ENABLE = var.app_env == "master" || var.app_env == "dev" ? "true" : "false"
```

According to the above condition value of the `OBJECT_ENABLE` key will be the following;

for `master` : **OBJECT_ENABLE** is `true`

for `dev` : **OBJECT_ENABLE** is `true`

for `staging` : **OBJECT_ENABLE** is `false`

Answer (score 4):

There's no binary type defined in Terraform. But you can try to use [simple math](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html#math)

E.g.

OR equivalent

```
 count = signum(${var.I_am_true} + ${var.I_am_false})
```

AND equivalent

```
 count = ${var.I_am_true} * ${var.I_am_false}
```

Both will work if I_am_true == 1 and I_am_false == 0.

Didn't try both, though.