# Multiple "OR" condition in shorthand IF statement (Terraform)

Tags: terraform

I needs to apply two conditions in order to work in one or the other in the short format necessary in Terraform.

I have working this one:

```
"${terraform.workspace == "test" ? true : false}"
```

And this working when workspace is "test", I need modify it into working on another environment like this:

```
"${terraform.workspace == "test" OR "preproduction" ? true : false}"
```

But here "OR" it's a only example. Then this be able to working if terraform.workspace is test or preproduction.

Thanks.

Comment: `"${(terraform.workspace == "test" || terraform.workspace == "preproduction") ? true : false}"`

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/51881306/2291321 answer your question?

Comment: Thanks! I missing full name of attribute like terraform.workspace after ||.