# Terraform: count and signum

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

Can someone please help me understand what it means when a count function is used with a signum that utilizes two variables. This is the line I don't understand:

```
count = "${signum(var.cluster_size_max * var.dynamic_autoscaling_enabled)}"
```

This is using terraform 11. The **var.cluster_size_max** is set to 1, and the **var.dynamic_autoscaling_enabled** is set to true. So as both are positive (1 & true) it will build the resource. But signum from the documentation checks the sign of a number so why has a *true/false* variable been put in here and how does signum read this if it's not a 1,0 or -1? What if the first variable was 0 or the second was false - do they both need to be positive for it to build?

Comment: This should answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39479849/is-there-a-way-and-or-conditional-operator-in-terraform

Comment: yes indeed, thank you @yvesonline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`false` will be treated as 0, thus **any value** of `var.cluster_size_max` will lead to 0, subsequently, `signum` will be 0.

> What if the first variable was 0 or the second was false

Since `dynamic_autoscaling_enabled` is false, signum will be 0 and no resource is created. Value of `cluster_size_max` does not matter in this case

> do they both need to be positive for it to build?

Yes. If `cluster_size_max` is negative, `count` will be -1 and you will get **terraform error** that count is negative.

Comment: thank you Marcin, but would that mean then that if dynamic_autoscaling_enabled was 'true' and cluster_size_max was "0" that it would still build? So it's the true or false value that overwrites the 0 or 1 value?

Comment: @scrow `0 x 1` is `0`, so it will not build.