# count = signum on number and bool

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I've seen answers to posts - [Is there a way AND/OR conditional operator in terraform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39479849/is-there-a-way-and-or-conditional-operator-in-terraform) - where it mentions that terraform will convert a bool to either 1 or 0, however, I can't get this to work - It seems this is specific to version 0.11 and earlier?

I'm trying to run a count using `signum(true * 0)` however this just keeps returning `invalid operand <bool/number> required`

This did work in terraform 11 but does not seem to as I try and upgrade to 12/13. We have a large repository and it would be easier if I could get this to work instead of converting all bools to numbers. Can someone please clarify if this is possible in versions 12 or later?

Full example is:

```
count = signum(var.cluster_size_max * var.with_external_elb)
```

where an external ELB is built if the `cluster_size_max` is set to 1 or more and `external_elb` is `true`.

Note: I've tried using `&&` instead of `signum` but this also doesn't work. The error I got was similar:

```
count                    = var.cluster_size_max && var.with_external_elb ? 1 : 0
----------------
var.cluster_size_max is 1
Unsuitable value for left operand: bool required.
```

Comment: Why are you trying to do some weird magic instead of writing it explicitly? `var.with_external_elb && var.cluster_size_max > 0 ? 1 : 0`

Comment: Hi Luke, thank you. I tested that out in the terraform console but that doesn't seem to work still as external_elb is a bool. I ran: 1 && true > 0 ? 1 :0    -- not sure if I'm missing something? The error is the same, that a number is required

Comment: there is a `> 0` in my first comment you must not simply omit or change the location of. `bool && int > threshold` is well-formed, `true && 1 > 0 ? 1 : 0` works.

Comment: ah sorry I wasn't thinking - I was trying to put the > 0 after bool. One other question. I guess if there is the &&, then there is no need for the signum as it will still only build 0 or 1. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: `signum` can return -1 which the current snippet cannot - but that is good thing because you do not need a -1 anyway.

Comment: ah yes. I suppose as I have the conditional it doesn't make a difference but might be good to keep anyway. Thank you Luke. That works in the console so should now fix my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to use the [`signum`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/signum.html) function for simple conditional statements.

Use `&&` as an *and*, use `>` to check the value of `var.cluster_size_max` & use `?` + `:` as a ternary operator to determine the final integer value of 1 or 0 based on the *and* result.

Try:

`count = var.with_external_elb && var.cluster_size_max > 0 ? 1 : 0`